# How to solve the bug in CheckBoxPreference Default Value in android?

Tags: java, android

Because my mainActivity does not run my Tab2Activity at startup until the user press the setting button to run the PreferenceActivity, therefore i have to first check the audioStatus boolean value in order to avoid unwanted boolean result but after this step i'm kinna lost because of the bug in CheckBoxPreference it gives me...

Now i don't know how to work with the logic comparison to get the audio even without navigating to Tab2Activity? Main problem here i'm facing is working with the logics yet getting the desirable result..

I'm kinna new in java/android and currently creating an car blackbox app can someone help me... Thanks :)

My mainActivity file

```
if(Tab2Activity.audioPref == false) 
    audioStatus = false;    
else
    audioStatus = Tab2Activity.audioPref; 

if(audioStatus == false)
   mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);

if(audioStatus == false)
   mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);
```

My Tab2Activity.java file

```
    public static boolean audioPref;
    public static String timeIntervalPref;

    public void getPrefs() {
         SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());

         audioPref = prefs.getBoolean("AudioPref", true);//Suppose to produce "false" isn't it?
         timeIntervalPref = prefs.getString("TimeIntervalPref", "60000");
    }
}
```

My xml file

```
<CheckBoxPreference
                android:title="Audio"
                android:defaultValue="True"
                android:summary="Select w/o Audio when Recording"
                android:key="AudioPref" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

save your settings to a SharedPreferences then read them from there rather than relying on the state of a public boolean in the Tab2Activity.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

example of use: 
http://saigeethamn.blogspot.com/2009/10/shared-preferences-android-developer.html

EDIT: I don't know why you are trying to get the preferences from tab2activity.
why wouldn't you do the following in mainActivity:

```
SharedPreferences prefs=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedreferences(getBaseContext()); 
audioStatus=prefs.getBoolean("AudioPref",true); // (only use true if you want the default to be true if the value has not yet been set, otherwise you should be doing ("AudioPref",false) )

if(!audioStatus) 
{ 
   mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC); 
   mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT); 
}
```

The bug you linked describes issues when you try to set default shared preference values to 'false'.  If you want that to be the default, then just use "false" as the default value when you go to retrieve the value using getBoolean(string,defValue)

Comment: my problem here is with CheckBoxPreference with only two state true/false not with the blog you gave me which only talk about other sort of Preferences... And CheckBoxPreference seems to have bug http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6641 , that's why i'm seeking help here to look for a more tengible solution for my situation here..

Comment: i know what you mean just have it at the mainActivity but i could not have it this way because my CheckBoxPreference is only initialized if i click on a Setting button to initialize my Tab2Activity.. That's why i have to first preset/default or "force" the audioplayer to record... But now i messed/confuse on how  should i solve this problem...